# How to use an old Kingston DataTraveler Vault Privacy USB flash drive on Linux?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, aes

My company provides me a DTVP with hardware AES encryption two years ago and the CDrom image does only contain tools for Windows and MacOS X. Kingston products now have support for Linux. Current version of [documentation and FAQ](http://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/products?model=DTVP) for DTVP flash drive now refers to Linux binaries.

How can I use my "old" USB flash drive on Linux ?

I have the following ideas but no detail information how to achieve any of them:

- update the ISO image on the flash drive to have Linux binaries on the key
- get binaries alone and run them from my Linux desktops

Comment: Kingston support has proposed me to replace my key by a more recent version with Linux code included... but my employer declined that offer. So I still run the .Net code from a windows virtual machine to unlock the device, and after deconnection from VM (the device remains physically connected and powered), I am able to mount the filesystem on Linux.

Comment: I have updated ISO image thanks to utility available at https://www.kingston.com/fr/support/technical/downloads/111289 but the "less-than-10mb" image does not contain Linux binaries even if included User's Guide PDF describes usage in Linux environment...